# How do I "unlike" a built-in like in a single request?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

When you want to "unlike" a built-in like action on an open graph object, you have to send an HTTP `DELETE` with the id of the like story itself. But that requires either:

1. Querying the graph for the ID of the story before deleting it, or
2. Stashing the ID that's returned when you create the like in the first place.

Neither of these are satisfying solutions. It would be nice to be able to do this all in a single request, preferably with nothing more than the URL of the liked object.

Because this modifies the graph, the Graph API has to be used, right? AFAIK, FQL is still read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half the battle is figuring out a way to use the Graph API to look up the ID of the like story given the URL of the liked object:

```
GET http://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes?object=http://url.to/your/object&fields=id
```

Once you have that, you can name it in a batch query, then refer to it from the DELETE request  using JSONPath (details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) under "Specifying dependencies between operations in the request"):

```
POST http://graph.facebook.com/
batch=[
  {"method":"GET", "name":"like_id", "relative_url":"me/og.likes?object=http://url.to/your/object&fields=id"},
  {"method":"DELETE", "relative_url":"?id={result=like_id:$.data[0].id}"}
]
```

Comment: I have a question: even if this method works for retrieving the like_id, I don't find this use of the API specified in any part of the documentation. So I'm actually afraid FB could eventually block this...

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes) gives you the OG path of "/me/og.likes" to query your likes. Enter than into the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Fog.likes). Click on the `+` button and notice one of the modifiers it suggests is "object". Seems pretty legit to me.